# SonarQube JDK 11

Tags: java, sonarqube, java-11, openjdk-11

WE are migrating our project from JDK 8 to JDK 11.
In JDK 8 everything works fine, with JDK 11 we have a problem running SonarQube:

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar
```

The error is this:

```
14:29:38  [INFO] Download sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.8.0.1168.jar
14:29:40  [ERROR] Initialization failed
14:29:40  javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found
14:29:40    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:152)
14:29:40    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:299)
14:29:40    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
14:29:40    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
14:29:40    at com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.access.persistence.JaxbAdapter.<init>(JaxbAdapter.java:102)
14:29:40    at com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.access.persistence.XmlAccess.createExportMetaDataJaxbAdapter(XmlAccess.java:39)
14:29:40    at com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.access.persistence.XmlExportMetaDataReader.readMetaDataFromStream(XmlExportMetaDataReader.java:75)
14:29:40    at com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.access.controller.MetaDataControllerImpl.internLoadExportMetaData(MetaDataControllerImpl.java:78)
14:29:40    at com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.access.controller.MetaDataControllerImpl.loadExportMetaData(MetaDataControllerImpl.java:66)
14:29:40    at com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.sonarqube.SonargraphBase.readBuiltInMetaData(SonargraphBase.java:340)
14:29:40    at com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.sonarqube.SonargraphMetrics.getMetrics(SonargraphMetrics.java:63)
....
....
....
14:29:40  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
14:29:40    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
14:29:40  [ERROR] Sonargraph Integration: Failed to load built in meta data from '/com/hello2morrow/sonargraph/integration/sonarqube/ExportMetaData.xml' - Failure: Load data from stream
14:29:40  Error - Read Error.
14:29:40  java.lang.NullPointerException
14:29:40  com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.access.persistence.JaxbAdapter.load(JaxbAdapter.java:144)
```

Comment: Add version of SonarQube server and all installed plugins (like SonarJava), please.